# Loosing Engine Power Mid to High RPM

Tags: engine, suzuki, swift

Have a Suzuki Swift that stalls from mid to high RPM in all gears. It runs great in low RPMS. The Engine was  overhauled. What are things to look for?

---

after the original question opened it. It says g13b on the block. I think that means G13BA since the later years swifts have G13bb
[image]

I think this is supposed to be how it looks (g10A)

[image]

If it is set up this way the distributor is hitting #4. Also a video saying that it is the case

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NoXtszhY0R8

Why is this correct?? if this is correct then the original position was a few tooths off since the pin is at 5 instead of 6 oclock. **why is does it hit #4 instead of #1??**

another thing this part should be another question. The pick that hits the cylinders on the distributor. The original part which is partially broken is has one side slightly longer than the other side. It is not centered. The replacement part is centered. Does that matter.

Comment: Did the rebuild entail boring the cylinders, thus increasing the displacement?

Comment: yes, It is 1.3 liter originally. It is like a bee. The machinist said that the engine could still be bore one more time. I'll put up a video or something. This car gets 40 mpg.  Bought  the Suzuki Aerio AWD 2.3 liter but the mpg is 28 as replacement

Comment: I'm wondering if it is fuel starved on the top end.

Comment: @Paulster2. The fuel pump filter was running great before. I think we even ran fuel pressure test. My dad beliefs it is something with the distributor not advancing. The car also do sent have the RPM sensor connected from the transmission.  He says it is nothing with the head. That he checked the valves springs.  The car needs to be set in the right RPM in Idle. It is OBD1  if it was OBD2 I would be able to access the sensors.  We will try to set the right RPM sometime next week.

Comment: Are you sure the cam timing is correct?  Could be 1 tooth off.  Did you follow the correct procedure for setting the ignition timing?  For computer controlled ignition, you typically need to set it to not advance the timing, so you can set the base timing.  You should be able to see the A/F ratio by measuring the voltage at the o2 sensor.  should be around .5v for stoich.  Should be decently rich (.8+) at WOT.